# How to use RETURN SETOF RECORD with dynamic column?

Tags: postgresql

I have some problem to get value of query. I need to get return with dynamic column according to query. For this case i can't use RETURN TABLE statement because we must define the column. Please Help :). Thank you

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.FN_test(P_Company varchar, P_fiscal_periode varchar, P_opt int)
  RETURNS SETOF RECORD
AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
Details RECORD;

BEGIN
    create table Details as
    select * from M_Account;

    RETURN QUERY select * from Details;
    drop table Details;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

this is result error

```
select FN_test('1000', '201808', 4)
> ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
  CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fn_test(character varying,character varying,integer) line 9 at RETURN QUERY
```

Comment: Try :  RETURNS SETOF M_Account.  As it currently exists the function is essentially "select * from m_accounts" , however,  due to the parameters I assume there's more to it. As it stands the Details table is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you return a record type, you must define the columns in the list to return from these functions(when you call it) and call the function with this format:

```
select * from FN_test('1000', '201808', 4) 
as (f1 data type, f2 data type) --list of columns
```

Could also return a JSON type (as generic resuldt) and then process it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.FN_test3(P_Company varchar, P_fiscal_periode varchar, P_opt int)
 RETURNS setof json
 AS $BODY$
 DECLARE 
  Details RECORD;

 BEGIN
     create table Details as
     select row_to_json(M_Account.*) from M_Account; --JSON function

     RETURN QUERY select * from Details;
     drop table Details;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

and the call it:

```
select  * from FN_test('1000', '201808', 4)
```